# How do i get Date back from sql Database to netbeans jdatechooser when i execute search query?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

when i execute search query, i get an error "java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set." i want to get the date from my DB to on jDateChoser. This is what i tried , please help me out ! Thanks in advance!

```
try { 
        Statement s = DB2.kavish().createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Invoice_No='"+jTextField28.getText()+"'");

        while (rs.next());

        jTextField29.setText(rs.getString(2));
        jTextField30.setText(rs.getString(3));
        jTextField31.setText(rs.getString(4));
        jTextField32.setText(rs.getString(5));
        jTextField33.setText(rs.getString(6));
        jTextField34.setText(rs.getString(7));
        jTextField35.setText(rs.getString(8));
        jDateChooser1.setDate(rs.getDate(9));


    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can I just make a point? Please never ever create SQL directly based on input from a text field. You'll want to use a PreparedStatement, not a Statement, and place a '?' (or a name) for the input parameter to avoid common [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following way

```
try{ 
Statement s = DB2.kavish().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Invoice_No='"+jTextField28.getText()+"'");

        while (rs.next()){

        jTextField29.setText(rs.getString(2));
        jTextField30.setText(rs.getString(3));
        jTextField31.setText(rs.getString(4));
        jTextField32.setText(rs.getString(5));
        jTextField33.setText(rs.getString(6));
        jTextField34.setText(rs.getString(7));
        jTextField35.setText(rs.getString(8));
        jDateChooser1.setDate(rs.getDate(9));

}
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you have semicolon `;` here in this line `while (rs.next());`
 remove it

Initially, the cursor is positioned before the first row. The method rs.next moves the cursor to the next row. This method returns false if the cursor is positioned after the last row. This method repeatedly calls the ResultSet.next method with a while loop to iterate through all the data in the ResultSet.
You are trying to retrieve after while loop that means that cursor is already at the bottom so no datas are there.Hence its throwing exception

**Note**

to prevent from `SQL Injection` go for `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` as follows

```
PreparedStatement pt=DB2.kavish().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Invoice_No=?");
pt.setString(1,jTextField28.getText());
ResultSet rs=pt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()){

    jTextField29.setText(rs.getString(2));
    jTextField30.setText(rs.getString(3));
    jTextField31.setText(rs.getString(4));
    jTextField32.setText(rs.getString(5));
    jTextField33.setText(rs.getString(6));
    jTextField34.setText(rs.getString(7));
    jTextField35.setText(rs.getString(8));
    jDateChooser1.setDate(rs.getDate(9));

}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```